# Need to sum digits in random numbers from loop

Tags: java, loops, random, modulus, digits

I'm randomly generating 3 digit numbers using java.util.Random(). The number of random 3-digit numbers that the system prints is controlled by user input. Here's the code:

```
//If/then statement for determining game type (determines 3 digit numbers)
if (gameType == 3) 

//for loop to generate random numbers (numGames is how many 3 digit numbers     to print)
for (int i = 1; i <=numGames; i = i + 1){

int ranNums = randomGenerator.nextInt((999 - 100) + 1) + 100; 

//Print random numbers to user
System.out.println(ranNums);

sumNums = ranNums % 10;
```

Basically, I want the code to add the DIGITS that are printed from the random number generator. For example, if the ranNums output is 111 and 111, I want the variable sumNums to equal 6, not 222. With the code I have now, it only adds the last digit of each number, (in this case 1 + 1 = 2).

Comment: Instead of generating random ints and splitting them into separate digits, why not just generate random digits and store them separately?  In other words, instead of generating [111,234], why not generate [[1,1,1],[2,3,4]], so that the digits are already separated?

Comment: I am open to doing this as well - but I'm not sure how I would write the code for that. Can you help?

Comment: Practice working with collections, like arrays, lists, etc.  Get to the point where you can make a collection of collections, and then make a list of 3-element arrays.  The rest is easy - randomly generate digits from 1-9 for the first of the 3 digits, 0-9 for the second and third digits.

Comment: I'm still confused though.  Ultimately, here's what I'm doing....I'm taking user input to simulate a lottery game. User inputs "3", then the game is pick 3 (3 numbers). Then, the user inputs how many games they want to play. For instance, if they choose 10 games, then the system will generate 10 sets of 3 numbers for them. I need to keep it simple without the use of array's because that would jump ahead of topics we haven't covered in class yet. So is there a better way to do this than just generating a 3-digit number for each game?

Comment: Yes, do nested loops.  The outer loop goes from 1..numGames, the inner loop goes from 1..gameType.  Inside the inner loop, generate a random digit and add to the sum.  In the outer loop, print the sum and reset the sum to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
sumNums = (n / 100) + (n / 10 % 10) + (n % 10);
```

Comment: That works! Now I just need to figure out how to apply it to all of the numbers generated by the loop. Right now, this only applies to the last number generated.

Comment: Correct `{}` for the for loop and it should work for all numbers generated

Comment: just use ranNums instead of n

Comment: Right - did that, but it still only adds the second number... I know the answer is right in front of my face, but I get flustered and start over thinking it....

Comment: //If/then statement for determining game type
        if (gameType == 3) 
        //for loop to generate random numbers     
        for (int i = 1; i <=numGames; i = i + 1){
            ranNums = randomGenerator.nextInt((999 - 100) + 1) + 100;  
            //Print random numbers to user
            System.out.println(ranNums);
                                                                                                   sumNums = (ranNums / 100) + (ranNums / 10 % 10) + (ranNums % 10);    
       
        }

Comment: put it in the question please

Comment: Sorry - I'm still new here :) Actually, I think a better way to accomplish this would be to generate 3 digits that are NOT a number. For example, how would I generate 1 2 3 instead of 123?